# Cant render image with transparent background after motion track?

Tags: rendering

[image: i have tried deleting the movie clip node]So i motion tracked a footage setup a scene did compositing and stuff so now i want only the 3d stuff without the video as a background. so i turned off the video, even tried turning off compositing in post processing, transperency is on in cycles,... but no matter what i do the renderer would render an image with transparency but when i save it as a png the background comes black. i have been banging my head for the past hour and just cannot fix this.

I beleive its because its rendering the foreground and then the background... i cant get it to render only one layer like it normally does on a new blender file. Even tried deleting the background layer and asking it to render a single layer.[image: This is the renderer view]
[image: this is the final png image which dosent save with he transparency]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your Compositing node setup?

Comment: there added it.. got added to the top tho...

Comment: Make sure to use RGBA (A as in Alpha) for your PNG output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Cy4.png

Comment: i could kiss you right now it worked.... I always keep it in RGBAA.. even blender default is RGBA.. i have no idea how it got changed to rgb.... thanks a lot .. my head hurts from all the  imagining myself banging my head on teh keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use RGBA (A as in Alpha) for your PNG output

[image]